# Deprecated ManagedQuery() issue

Tags: java, android, deprecated

I have this method:

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Unfortunately the compiler show me a problem on:

```
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
```

Because `managedQuery()` is deprecated.

How could I rewrite this method without use `managedQuery()`?

Answer (score 266, accepted):

You could replace it with `context.getContentResolver().query` and `LoaderManager` (you'll need to use the compatibility package to support devices before API version 11).

However, it looks like you're only using the query one time: you probably don't even need that. Maybe this would work?

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String res = null;
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){;
       int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
       res = cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return res;
}
```

Comment: ops... no doesn't works in any case... if the uri starts with "file://" doesn't returns the right path

Comment: `file://` URIs generally can't be resolved using `contentUri`: if you have a file URI you ALREADY have the real path.

Comment: Could you give me more details? I have an "Uri", my problem is to get the real absolute path without file://, /content:/ and others attributes.

Comment: For a content URI, you'll need a resolver to get a file URI, and once you have a file URI you can just do `new File(new URI(uri.getPath()));`.

Comment: but I have to send only the absolute path to an external specific library ... so I need a solution to get the absolute path from the Uri

Comment: Ah, sure: `new File(new URI(uri.getPath())).getAbsolutePath();` is what you need, no?

Comment: But in this way ...what about file extension? The user will receive a file without any extension?

Comment: btw with new File(new URI(uri.getPath())).getAbsolutePath(); I get the Exception URI is not absolute. I have marked your answer because answers the initial question, however I haven't solved my problem :(

Comment: Hey did you figure out the solution at the end AndreaF

Comment: Thanks! getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null); works nicely.

Comment: This code has an extra semicolon at the end of ` if(cursor.moveToFirst()){;`

Answer (score 3):

```
public void getBrowserHist(Context context) {
        Cursor mCur = context.getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
                Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
        mCur.moveToFirst();
        if (mCur != null && mCur.moveToFirst() && mCur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (mCur.isAfterLast() == false) {
                Log.e("hist_titleIdx",
                        mCur.getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_TITLE_INDEX));
                Log.e("hist_urlIdx",
                        mCur.getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_URL_INDEX));
                mCur.moveToNext();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -8):

you need to initialize the cursor becauese it will be close before method start or some where else

```
cursor = null;
public void method(){
// do your stuff here 
cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: Initialize cursor helps with deprecated method, really?