# Get all captured Videos in Android as a list

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-gallery, mediastore

I am trying to get all video available in gallery with below code,

```
 String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE };
 videocursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,proj, null,null, null);
int count = videocursor.getCount();
```

But I always get `count = 0`, where was I made mistake ?

I also tried

```
Cursor videocursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj, null, null, null);
```

Comment: did you check that your video files included in "MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI"?

Comment: I had capture video from device camera application, and it's available there I checked with File Manager application

Answer (score 0):

***Do like this -***

```
String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Video.Media._ID, MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE,};

 String orderBy = android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE;

 Cursor videocursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
               proj, null, null, orderBy);
```

To get the size, you can use

```
 int count = videocursor.getCount();
```

***EDIT*** [`managedQuery()` is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12714701/deprecated-managedquery-issue#12714830)

Comment: @Hitesh_Androiduser3797630 - Updated the answer. Try it.

Comment: I'll check, Can I add in proj for video thumbnail ?

Comment: @Hitesh_Androiduser3797630 - Use the proj as is mentioned in the answer.