# Android Xamarin get absolute path from Android.Net.Uri

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have and Xamarin Android application that needs the users to get a file from the internal storage and then read the file.

The file picker I'm using returns the file as an `Android.Net.Uri` object. Here's how the object is coming:

[image]

Then to read the file I'm using `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename)`. The problem is that this method cannot find the file with this path.

I tried `Path.GetFullPath(uri.Path)` but it returns the same value I'm passing in.

How can I get the absolute path of the file for such `Uri` object?

Also, the file could be in any folder, not only in the `Download` folder as in the example.

Comment: Can you provide the file picker code of your project?

Comment: I think the way to go is: `1. File f = new File(Uri); var absp = f.AbsolutePath;`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and finally found a good solution approach here:

[Xamarin Choose Image From Gallery Path is Null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597811/xamarin-choose-image-from-gallery-path-is-null)

Only tricky part for me was:
a) find the ContentResolver, as I am not in an Activity, but in a fragment:

```
this.View.Context.ContentResolver
```

b) find ManagedQuery Object, which is also a property of the Activity

```
this.Activity.ManagedQuery
```

c) provide correct selection, as I had an image it was from the MediaStore:

```
string selection = Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Id + " =? ";
```

I hope this still helps you, although it was 2 months ago.

```
private string GetPathToImage(Android.Net.Uri uri) {
    string doc_id = "";
    using (var c1 = this.View.Context.ContentResolver.Query(uri, null, null, null, null)) {
        c1.MoveToFirst();
        String document_id = c1.GetString(0);
        doc_id = document_id.Substring(document_id.LastIndexOf(":") + 1);
    }

    string path = null;

    // The projection contains the columns we want to return in our query.
    string selection = Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Id + " =? ";
    using (var cursor = this.Activity.ManagedQuery(Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri, null, selection, new string[] { doc_id }, null)) {
        if (cursor == null) return path;
        var columnIndex = cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Data);
        cursor.MoveToFirst();
        path = cursor.GetString(columnIndex);
    }
    return path;
}
```

Comment: It says the `ManagedQuery` line is deprecated, do you perhaps have the new way to query?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12714701/deprecated-managedquery-issue Have a look here, I think this.Activity.ContentResolver.Query should be the proper replacement - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26120999/464016