# I have confusion in SqlQuerylBuilder

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

Sorry if this question have been asked before . Why `SqlQueryBuilder` class is used in `ContentProvider`

1) For what purpose `SqlQueryBuilder` class is used for ?

2) what this method does?

```
 qb.setTables(STUDENTS_TABLE_NAME);
 qb.setProjectionMap(STUDENTS_PROJECTION_MAP);
 qb.appendWhere( _ID + "=" + uri.getPathSegments().get(1));
```

3) I noticed in content resolver that to call content provider `query().managedQuery()` is used . Why this method is used?

Answer (score 0):

SQLiteQueryBuilder is a convience class that helps build SQL queries.
Try this documentation for APIs usage:

```
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html
```

Comment: managedQuery is deprecated from API 11 onwards.
Refer this if you looking for alternative:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12714701/deprecated-managedquery-issue